# Jquery zoom wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, zooming

i'm trying to implement Jquery [zoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom) on my Joomla driven website on the catalog images. I cant get this thing to work, so can anybody help me solve this problem?

I've added the these scripts in the head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.myurl.mk/templates/beez_20/javascript/jquery.zoom.js"></script>
```

here is the error it gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'
(anonymous function)
```

[here is link to a example of my site](http://zasvadba.mk/kategorii/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B07.html)

here is my code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#ex1').zoom({url: '<?php echo $this->item->imageXLarge; ?>'});
        });
    </script>
      <div class="itemImageBlock" style="float:none;">
          <span class="itemImage" id="ex1">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->item->image; ?>" alt="<?php if(!empty($this->item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->title); ?>" style="width:<?php echo $this->item->imageWidth; ?>px; height:auto;" />
          </span>
```

Comment: You should add jquery script before all script files. jQuery is not available while you trying at that point

Comment: @Shusl added the scripts in the head

Comment: I believe your problem is solved? I can see it working

Comment: @Shusl no the problem is still here...

Comment: @Shusl the scripts were inserted before asking the question

Comment: I don't see any problem now on http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom. You should clean your browser cache.

Comment: @Shusl cleared but still not working?? Can you post a print screen

Comment: -1 because once you fix your site this question will be useless to future readers.  It can be improved by showing the relevant broken code.  Also, on your site, you are still including jQueryUI _before_ jQuery... it will never work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your page and found that you are loading jQuery file after depended files. There is many error in console. first one is jQuery not defined. Move your jQuery file before all other script files.

After moving jQuery on top your site is looking fine. I attached an snapshot as you requested.
[image]

Comment: Please improve this answer by explaining what exactly _"moving jQuery on top"_ is supposed to mean.  I know what you meant, but let's make these answers more meaningful for everyone by showing the code and explaining what exactly was done.

Comment: Thanks, I explained reason behind error he was getting.

Answer (score 1):

On your example page, you're importing ks2.js before jquery.js.

This should be the first item after your `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```